# Swift 3 animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, caanimation

I am implementing progress view that simply animate colors.

Everything is working fine exept "strokeEnd" animation that is filling by shape and making it to flicker.

Video [resource](http://sendvid.com/0t3wnvhe)

Code example:

```
class MaterialCircularProgressView: UIView {

    let circularLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let googleColors = [
        UIColor(red:0.282, green:0.522, blue:0.929, alpha:1),
        UIColor(red:0.859, green:0.196, blue:0.212, alpha:1),
        UIColor(red:0.957, green:0.761, blue:0.051, alpha:1),
        UIColor(red:0.235, green:0.729, blue:0.329, alpha:1)
    ]

    let inAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0
        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

        return animation
    }()

    let outAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        animation.beginTime = 0.5
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0
        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)

        return animation
    }()

    let rotationAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 2 * M_PI
        animation.duration = 2.0
        animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT

        return animation
    }()

    var colorIndex : Int = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        circularLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
        circularLayer.fillColor = nil
        layer.addSublayer(circularLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2 - circularLayer.lineWidth / 2

        let arcPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2 + (2 * M_PI)), clockwise: true)

        circularLayer.position = center
        circularLayer.path = arcPath.cgPath

        animateProgressView()
        circularLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotateAnimation")
    }


    func animateProgressView() {

        circularLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "strokeAnimation")

        circularLayer.strokeColor = googleColors[colorIndex].cgColor

        let strokeAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        strokeAnimationGroup.duration = 1.0 + outAnimation.beginTime
        strokeAnimationGroup.repeatCount = 1
        strokeAnimationGroup.animations = [inAnimation, outAnimation]
        strokeAnimationGroup.delegate = self

        circularLayer.add(strokeAnimationGroup, forKey: "strokeAnimation")

        colorIndex += 1;
        colorIndex = colorIndex % googleColors.count;
    }
}


extension MaterialCircularProgressView: CAAnimationDelegate{

    override func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        if(flag) {
            animateProgressView()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that flickering by setting strokeStart to the final value of your `outAnimation` in the initializer:

```
circularLayer.strokeStart = 1.0
```

The reason is that actual value of property animated by `CAPropertyAnimation` is not automatically set to the `toValue` of animation, so it reverts to it's original value which is `0.0` in your case. That's why a full circle appears for some time.

However there is a delay before next circle appears, not sure if that was your intention or another bug to be fixed.